# React MultiSelect component showing` Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use `Multiselect` (from `multiselect-react-dropdown`) component to get multiple values from a user. For this I've written the below code

```
 <Multiselect
              options={
                allItemsData && allItemsData.map((item) => item.name)
              }
              onChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
            />
```

allItemsData is an array of objects in which each object consist of id, name, price, etc. The code just creates an empty number of options in the list that is equal to the size of an array. When I click the on it, or try to select/deselect it just shows the following error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
```

I just don't know what is undefined here. allItems array is not empty. I'm beginner to React. What is causing this error?

Comment: what is this ? (reading 'toLowerCase')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In multiselect react drop down options are expected as an array of object with id and name in it.
check the library documentation in npm or github

```
{
    options: [{name: 'Option 1️⃣', id: 1},{name: 'Option 2️⃣', id: 2}]
};
```

in your case try this

```
options={allItemsData && allItemsData.map((item) => {name: item.name, id:item.id})
```

if you dont have id in your items try adding index or name itself

Comment: allItemsData.map(item=> {
                return { name: item.name, id: item.id }})
Tried this, still the same error

Comment: console your allItems data and share here